# MEAN.IO restarting server causes state routes to fail

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean.io

Sometimes when we start the server we attempt to go to a page and get the error "Could not resolve resReports from state 'home' ".  Sometimes the error says it could not resolve from state ' '. We have to restart the server again until it works.  This happens intermittently, so is difficult to troubleshoot.

When the error occurs we see in aggregated.js that our routes are being called before the controllers,  when everything is working fine aggregated.js shows the controllers before the routes.

Our routes are inside a MEAN generated Package. Routes below:

```
angular.module('mean.reports').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('resReports', {
                url: '/reports/reservations',
                templateUrl: 'reports/views/reservations.html',
                controller: 'ResReportsController'
            })
            .state('device reports', {
                url: '/reports/devices',
                templateUrl: 'reports/views/devices.html',
                controller: 'DeviceReportsController'
            });
    }
]);
```